# Delphi 10 Seattle TabControl Style like android in windows

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm using TabControl on Delphi 10 Seattle in Windows 8.1.

Windows style:

[image: Windows Style]

Android Style:

[image: Android Style]

How to get the Android style for the TabControl in Windows?

Comment: Your question is not clear! What you show is what you want or is it what you don't want? You show show what you want.

Comment: I run the App on Windows. And the tabcontrol looks like the figure above. Is it possible to make it look like the bottom figure?

Comment: I edited your question to make your comment apparent. For the future, please learn how to properly format your question. I have no definitive answer, but I think it is possible to use `custom style` for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention and correction of my question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the style designer (add a StyleBook to the form and double click).
2. Load the mobile style you want to use (you have to use AndroidLLight.fsf if you want the look&feel above). Located in the public Style folder. It end’s with *.fsf
3. Save it to a location you prefer. (Now the file extension *.style)
4. Open the style in a text editor.
5. Search for the object TStyleDescription and delete the whole section.
6. In your project file (*.dpr) add the unit FMX.Style and at the first code line TStyleManager.SetStyleFromFile().

Comment: I do it and it worked, thank you very much